# Make program think that it's connecting to one IP, but spoof it with another

Tags: windows, ip, spoofing

There's program that can connect to servers, but it's limited to 6 predefined IPs (although it has ability to connect to other IPs, don't ask why and how). I can't modify it.

I need to connect to another public IP using that program. How can I make it think it's connecting to own predefined IP, but for real connect to IP defined by me? (Windows)

Connection goes using two ports, one UDP and one TCP.

Answer (score 1):

Is it in your LAN ? as such just put a second IP on your NIC (the fake IP), and make sure the other server got a second IP in the same range too, so no traffic will hit the gateway.

Comment: None of them are in my LAN.

Comment: @Andrew do you control the router in from of that server ?

Comment: no, i only control my computer and program.